# Server configuration

Tags: vps, bandwidth, dedicated-server, linode

I currently use Linode VPS (512) for my image sharing site.

I'm looking to move to an unmetered dedicated server as the cost of my needs on Linode is huge.

I have around 60-70GB/day of outgoing data and I need more disk space.

My problem is, there are SO many hosting companies out there, and even more review sites.

I'm trying to find someone with good experience with a dedicated servers company, that is not too expensive.

Thanks!

EDIT: As for needs, I am looking for a Linux based server (Ubuntu/CentOS), and as for specs, I'm currently using the Linode 512 and it's barely handling the amount of visitors. But I suspect that almost any dedicated server configuration will have more than 512mb RAM and CPU should be stronger too, right?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Unfortunately product recommendations are off-topic here, as they are not only subjective but can become very irrelevant very quickly. In future when other people browse this question, the information will possibly be out of date or factually incorrect, and we don't like misinformation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question I'd a but too vague. It depends on what server specs are required. What OS do you need? Windows/Linux. CPU… RAM… Hard drive. 
I use Melbourne Server Hosting. http://qyk.in/melbourne With data centres in Manchester, UK. They have the best service I have had from any company. They may be a bit more expensive than the larger companies (1&1, etc) but it is worth it. I have had many problems with the large hosting companies like 1&1 and fasthosts. All you have to do is google 1&1 problems and you will find out. 
Hope this helps

Comment: I have edited my question to include my needs. Yes, I have dealt with 1&1 in the past and I wouldn't like to deal with them again..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a budget in mind?  As another Linode user, I would try to stick with them.  Transferring that amount of traffic per day, I would assume (HOPE!) that your site is earning some revenue that could more than pay for a larger Linode plan.